# Logistic Regression - malty classification

Tags: machine-learning, computational-mathematics

[image]

I want to understand why the probability of P(D|p) is presented as a product of mentioned probabilities.
I read a lot of texts, but everywhere the explanations are full of terminologies to confuse the reader.

Thanks!!!

Comment: They are assuming that the $y_i$ are independent and identically distributed. This means that their joint distribution is the product of their individual distributions, which is exactly what is written there.

Comment: I was thinking shouldn't the P(D|p)=Prod[k to M](Pk)

Comment: What's $k$ in that context? I think you're just getting confused by the abbreviated notation. You're really calculating $P(Y_1=y_1,Y_2=y_2,\dots,Y_n=y_n|P(Y=1)=p_1,\dots,P(Y=M)=p_M)$.

Comment: can you please make a small example by numbers please?

Comment: $P(Y_1=1,Y_2=2,Y_3=1|P(Y=1)=1/3,P(Y=2)=2/3)=1/3 \cdot 2/3 \cdot 1/3 = 2/27$.

Comment: ok looks like I got it, that means the probability of data D under distribution of P is the product of all individual probabilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y_i$ be random variable that shows the value of data in the $i$th experiment. Because of the assumption that data is gathered from independent and identically distributed (with distribution $p$) experiments, $Y_i$s are IID random variables. Therefore you have:

$$
\begin{align}
P(D\mid p) &= P(Y_1=y_1, Y_2 = y_2, \dots ,Y_n = y_n \mid p) \\ &= P(Y_1 = y_1\mid p)P(Y_1 = y_1\mid p)\dots P(Y_n = y_1\mid p)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will think little bit to get the idea